# unable to create .apk file for sench touch application

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i have developed Sencha Application.i want an apk file to test on Device.i refered sencha Docs for it.all the commands works fine except "sencha package build config.json" .i have attached error file ["here"](http://i50.tinypic.com/5dpdgz.jpg).And configuration file here ["json configuration"](http://www.dropbox.com/s/rtzpp444e4xjbxj/config.json).
i waste 3 days to solve this issue.
so help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have some where Program Files...... so dir is with space. To fix it use
"c:/program files/dir..." so that dir should be in quotes

Comment: i have install sench touch cmd in C:\sench directory without any namespaces then it work for me,

Comment: So as i said issue was in Folder name :) If my answer help you mark as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, can you say the version of sencha? and the sencha CMD are you using?

Please check: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/command, it's the place where the CMD documentation for the Sencha Touch 2.1 it's stored.